Chunking documents for Azure AI Search - RAG
I am looking for an automated 'pythonic' solution of automating the creation of search index as a source to my RAG tool. It is the same question as here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2130086/how-to-create-an-index-and-indexer-for-rag-solutio?comment=question#newest-question-comment .
As there are many docs / sources I just wanted to ask which approach is better for this case - using LangChain chunking like here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/data-chunking/langchain-data-chunking-example.ipynb
OR the SplitSkill with 'pages' like here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-python-samples/blob/main/Tutorial-RAG/Tutorial-rag.ipynb
What is the difference? Does SplitSkill treat documents in the similiar way like the Langchain RecursiveTextSplitter?
